# Laravel query that includes a != is not working

Tags: php, laravel

I have a query in a function and it's working fine except if I want to exclude something. In this case, all entries with virtual = 1 should be excluded.

```
public function index()
   {
    $products = $this->product->where('active', '1')->where('virtual', '!=', '1')->get();
   }
```

But if I add the where with != the result includes ONLY the entries with value 1 instead of all with value 0. So the opposite.

What do I miss here?

Comment: Try changing `$this->product` to `$this->product()`.

Comment: instead of `->get();` use `->dd()` and show result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$this->product` Does not return a `Builder` instance, and by naming should return a single `Product` or `null`. I assume this should be named `products` (a `one-to-many` relationship) and return a `Collection`.

`Collection`s have a `where()` method, but it doesn't accept operators, so the first `where()` works, but the second one does not. `Collection`s also have `get()` method, but requires at least one parameter. Yours should be throwing the error:

> Missing argument 1 for Illuminate\Support\Collection::get()

Anyway, explanation aside, to solve this issue, make sure you're using the `Builder` class by including `()` on your relationship call:

```
$products = $this->products()->where('active', '1')->where('virtual', '!=', '1')->get();
```

Note: Changed name to `products()`; relationships that return a `Collection` should be named to match.

Answer (score 3):

This is because you are using a collection and not an eloquent query :

Eloquent query :

```php
public function index()
   {
    $products = $this->product()->where('active', '1')->where('virtual', '<>', '1')->get();
   }
```

```php
public function index()
   {
    $products = $this->product->where('active', '1')->where('virtual', '!=', '1');
   }
```

Comment: All I get when adding product() is Method [product] does not exist.

Comment: @Oliver Have you set up a relationship in the model?

Comment: what is $this->product ? Maybe just try Product::where('active', '1')->... instead if you just have a Product Model